# Assigning values to dynamically generated row in html?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have below html which generates dynamic rows as below.

```
<html>
   <head>
      <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.5.1.min.js"></script>
      <script>
         $(document).ready(function() {
         var id = 0;
         // Add button functionality
         $("table.dynatable button.add").click(function() {
         id++;
         var master = $(this).parents("table.dynatable");
         // Get a new row based on the prototype row
         var prot = master.find(".prototype").clone();
         prot.attr("class", "")
         prot.find(".id").attr("value", id);
         master.find("tbody").append(prot);
         });
         // Remove button functionality
         $("table.dynatable button.remove").live("click", function() {
         $(this).parents("tr").remove();
         });
         });
      </script>
      <style>
         .dynatable {
         border: solid 1px #000;
         border-collapse: collapse;
         }
         .dynatable th,
         .dynatable td {
         border: solid 1px #000;
         padding: 2px 10px;
         width: 170px;
         text-align: center;
         }
         .dynatable .prototype {
         display:none;
         }
      </style>
   </head>
   <body>
      <table class="dynatable">
         <thead>
            <tr>
               <th>ID</th>
               <th>Name</th>
               <th>Col 3</th>
               <th>Col 4</th>
               <th><button class="add">Add</button></th>
            </tr>
         </thead>
         <tbody>
            <tr class="prototype">
               <td><input type="text" name="id[]" value="0" class="id" /></td>
               <td><input type="text" name="name[]" value="abc" /></td>
               <td><input type="text" name="col4[]" value="xyz" /></td>
               <td><input type="text" name="col3[]" value="sample" /></td>
               <td><button class="remove">Remove</button>
            </tr>
      </table>
   </body>
</html>
```

It works fine. But here values have been hard coded. usually i get these values from database and i can populated it using jstl tags. On click of Add  button it creates a row but it gives same values as in first row.

My question is is it possible to re-use the same row but without any values populated in it so that user can key in the values for the newly created row.

Also, how can I assign unique ids and names when the new row gets created? in above code id and names are hard coded.

Comment: Indent your code. Then maybe I'll read it and try to help. Bye.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at this demo .. [Check Here](http://jsfiddle.net/yUfhL/347/)

`Ids` are generated dynamically obviously with respect to `counter` ...

```
var counter = 1;
jQuery('a.add-author').click(function(event){
alert("asdas");
    event.preventDefault();
    counter++;
    var newRow = jQuery('<tr><td><input style="width:200px" type="text" name="designation' +
counter + '"/></td><td><input style="width:200px" type="text" id="start_date'+ counter +'" name="start_date' +
        counter + '"/></td><td><input style="width:200px" id="end_date'+ counter +'" type="text" name="end_date' +
        counter + '"/></td></tr>');
    jQuery('table.authors-list').append(newRow);
    jQuery("#start_date"+ counter).datepicker();
    jQuery("#end_date"+ counter).datepicker();
 //$(".enddate").datepicker();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
var prot = master.find(".prototype").clone();
prot.attr("class", "")
prot.find(".id").attr("value", id);

prot.find(':text,:hidden,select,textarea').val('');
prot.find(':checkbox,:radio').prop('checked', false);

master.find("tbody").append(prot);
```

Comment: Arun, Thanx for ur reply. If reuse the same tr then each component of the row will have same id and name. How can i assign unique id and name for the newly created row? Thanks!

Comment: you don't need to use `id`s here, prefer `class` to `id` in this situation

Comment: Atleast i have to use unique names right? so that i can get the input value in servlet using request.getParameter("uniqueName");

Comment: @user1016403 can you share the `prototype` row

Comment: Arun, prototype row is already there in my question. Please see tr with class prototype. Please ignore the css property called display:none for prototype..